# Add auto created_by and create_at fields in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wanna add properties such as "created_by" and "created_at" to each and every object in pretty much every collection in firestore.

The only approaches I can think of so far are.

1. Add them in the client-side code but verify them on the server side using Security Rules.

or better:

2. Add them automatically on the server side using [Cloud Firestore function triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers) onCreate and onWrite events.

However, both approaches sounds like workarounds for a very common task for which I would expect an out-of-the-box solution.

Does anybody know any out-of-the-box approach for that?

Comment: So to understand better, do you want to update all documents in Firestore, with two new fields that don't exist yet? How many documents exist in your db?

Comment: No, I don't yet have any data. I want these to be automatically added to any newly created object

Comment: So you want that all new documents that are added to have the new field configuration and the old ones will remain the same (without the two fields). Is that correct?

Comment: I don't have any old ones

Comment: Then I'm not sure where the problem is, since you're writing only new data.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in solution for this. Cloud Functions sounds redundant as security rules can ensure the values are correct:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.created_at == request.time && request.data.created_by == request.auth.uid;
```

You can use [`serverTimestamp()`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) for `created_at` when adding the document so the rules will return true as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time).

> For Firestore write operations that include server-side timestamps, this time (`request.time`) will be equal to the server timestamp.

---

You can use `withConverter()` so you don't have to repeat the same code to add those common fields. Instead, declare the converter once and use it for any read/write operations as required:

```js
const addDefaultFields = {
  toFirestore: (docData: any) => {
    // TODO: Add created_at and other fields 
    return {
      created_at: serverTimestamp(),
      ...docData,
    }
  },
  fromFirestore: (snapshot: any, options: any) => {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)
    return {
      id: snapshot.id,
      ...data,
    }
  },
}

const docRef = doc(db, 'col', 'alovelace').withConverter(addDefaultFields)
```