# How to automatically set updatedAt and createdAt on a Firebase document using PATCH over REST API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We use the Firebase REST API, specifically the PATCH method to both create and update documents in Firestore.

How do we get Google Firestore to behave like a DB by auto-populating createdAt and updatedAt fields in the documents with SERVER side values?

Again REST API is what we're using.

Thanks.

Didn't see anything in Google's docs and read a lot of chaos on the topic in various blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore is a NoSQL database and does not support auto generated timestamp fields. Even in databases like MongoDB, usually ORMs like Mongoose are used handle this. 
You would have to manually add those 2 fields are included in all requests and use security rules to ensure that values in the request are valid.

Checkout [Cloud Firestore REST API - Add server timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779415/cloud-firestore-rest-api-add-server-timestamp) to use `serverTimestamp()` with REST API so you won't have to pass actual timestamps from client side.

In case you use Firebase SDKs later, you can use converters as mentioned in this answer [Add auto created_by and create_at fields in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717610/add-auto-created-by-and-create-at-fields-in-firestore).

Comment: @sts yes, the timestamp is added on server side and works with update requests ,

Comment: Is not supported for PATCH. Of course google doesn't document that. Lame DB that is for sure.

Comment: as a workaround we are writing updatedAt ourselves from the client during PATCH.